# Linking problem with Three20

Tags: iphone

I'm using Three20 in my project. I added Three20 to my project using the python script supplied. Everything works fine when I compile and deploy my project onto the iphone 4 in debug mode, but when I try to build for distribution (Build and Archive) the compile fails with 2 linking errors.
Does any one know what this problem might be, and why I have no problem running the project on my iphone in debug mode?

The linking error (that appears twice) is:

> ld: file not found: ../Three20/facebook-three20-309d34e/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

```
Ld build/BDV.build/Distribution-iphoneos/BDV.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BDV normal armv7
cd /Users/fh/projects/iphone/BDV
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
```

Comment: linking problem Will come If Linking Between ViewControllers and XibSo remove Build And Remove All Connections .clearAllTargets.Now Check

Comment: Post your linking errors

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/1228) In future, if you have a problem editing one of your posts, please flag for moderator attention, do *not* add a new answer.